# Monitor a service running on a port other than 80 in Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios

How do we monitor a remote service running on a machine using Nagios.
I have created a cfg file as follows:

```
define command {
        command_name                    check_http
        command_line                    /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 8082
        }
```

Now when I reload the configuration file, it throws following error:

```
Warning: Duplicate definition found for command 'check_http' (config file '/etc/nagios/servers/cfbase-prod.cfg', starting on line 19)
Error: Could not add object property in file '/etc/nagios/servers/cfbase-prod.cfg' on line 20.
   Error processing object config files!
```

I am not able to figure out what is the problem.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the `command_name` value conflicts with the original/standard `check_http` command. You have (at least) a couple choices:

1. Set a unique `command_name`, e.g. `check_http_8082`.
2. Define a command to check http on an arbitrary port that gets passed as an argument. E.g.

   ```
   define command{
       command_name check_http_port
       command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p $ARG1$
   }
   ```